# Definition of "immersed plane curve"

Tags: differential-geometry

The exact meaning of immersed plane curve is not clear to me and I would like to request some help with clarifying it here:

A [plane curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_curve) is a map $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$. For example, the circle $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ is a plane curve.

An [immersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_%28mathematics%29) is a (smooth) map between (smooth) manifolds $f: M \to N$ such that the [pushforward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29) (=Jacobian matrix) is injective at every point in the domain.

I assumed that an immersed plane curve  must be a plane curve that is an immersion. But the Jacobian of a map $f(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ is given by $(x'(t) \  \  y'(t))$ and that, of course, is *not* going to have non-zero determinant for any $t$.

> What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *"of course"* is wrong; for example the curve $f(t)=(t,t^3)$ has derivative at $t=0$ that is not injective, namely the matrix $[0,0]$.

---

I'd misread your question - I thought you were asking if *every* plane curve was immersed, but now I see you were asking why *any* are.

Remember that *determinants only make sense for square matrices*, which I should have corrected you on earlier anyway - the relevant issue (the pushforward being injective) is equivalent to the matrix having *full rank*. For example, at $t=1$, the curve $f(t)=(t,t^3)$ has derivative $[1,3]$, which has rank $1=\min\{1,2\}$ (i.e., "full rank"). Equivalently, as a map $$\mathbb{R}\cong T_1\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow T_{(1,1)}\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{R}^2$$
it sends $s$ to $(s,3s)$, which is certainly injective.

Comment: Isn't this just what I say in my question? That the determinant is going to vanish so the Jacobian is not injective?

Comment: Determinants only make sense for square matrices. The relevant issue (being injective) is equivalent to the matrix having full rank. I've expanded my answer.